# browser fetches cljs source map files from wrong url

Tags: clojure, source-maps, boot-clj

I'm having problems accessing cljs source-map files from inside the browser. It looks like it is trying to fetch them from a wrong url. E.g:

```
http://localhost:3000/js/main.out/cljs/main.out/cljs/spec.cljs
```

But it should be rather:

```
http://localhost:3000/js/main.out/cljs/spec.cljs
```

The `main.cljs.edn` in my boot-clj project looks like this:

```
{:require  [myapp.core]
 :init-fns [myapp.core/init]
 :compiler-options {:asset-path "js/main.out"}}
```

Does anybody know how to fix this?